# Coin Change Problem: when must the largest coin be used?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, integer-programming

The coin change problem is as follows. Given coins with values $1 = c_1 < c_2 < \cdots < c_k$ and an amount
$M$, find nonnegative integers $a_i$ such that $\sum a_i c_i = M$ with
$\sum a_i$ as small as possible. (The $1$ is so that a solution is
possible for any $M$.)

The greedy algorithm, taking as many $c_k$ as possible, then as many $c_{k-1}$, and so on, is not always optimal for this problem (e.g. coins 1, 3, 4, target amount 6).

For $M$ large, there are always optimal solutions to the coin change problem using the largest coin $c_k$.  Explicitly, Chan and He in *More on Change Making and Related Problems* show that if $M > c_{k-1}c_k$ then there are optimal solutions using $c_k$.
The proof is as follows: if  $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1} b_i c_i = bc_k$ then no optimal solution has $a_i \geq b_i$ for all $i$, since we
can replace $\sum_{i=1}^{k-1}b_i c_i$ with $bc_k$ to get a strictly
better solution.  Now suppose we have any solution using $N$ non-$c_k$
coins with values $x_1, \ldots, x_N$, and let $s_i$ be the $i$th partial
sum of the $x_i$ for $i \geq 0$.  If $N \geq c_k$ then two of these
partial sums must be congruent mod $c_k$, so there is a sum of $x_i$s divisible by $c_k$, so the solution can be
improved. Thus any optimal solution not using $c_k$ must be to a problem
with $M$ at most $c_{k-1}c_k$.

**Is there a smaller bound $m$ such that if $M\geqslant m$, there are always optimal solutions that use the largest coin?**  If the greedy algorithm works for a particular set of coins then $m=c_k$ works, but I am interested in bounds valid for any coins.

Comment: The proof you provided states congruence mod $c_k$ only if $N\geq c_k$.  Additionally, how does the part of the proof involving $x_i$ relate or extend the proof involving $b_i$?

Comment: You can replace $\gt$ by $\ge$ in $M\gt c_{k-1}c_k$ (since for $M=c_{k-1}c_k$ the optimal solution is clearly $c_{k-1}$ coins of value $c_k$). Note that for $k=3$ with $c_3=c_2+1$, this bound is almost tight (the best bound in that case is $M\ge c_2^2-1$), so there's no bound that's significantly smaller in all cases (though it might be in some).